# JGit cannot clone Github repository

Tags: java, authorization, jgit

I'm trying to clone a private Github project, using JGit, as follows:

```
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setURI( "https://github.com/xxx/testing.git" );
cloneCommand.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "username", "password" ) );
cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\clone"));
cloneCommand.call();
```

I always got denied with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/xxx/testing.git: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:191)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:45)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/xxx/testing.git: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1462)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:238)
    ... 3 more
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: If you are using github's user's password note that password authentication is been shutdown you need toe use token based authentication for HTTP. https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/#what-you-need-to-do-today

Comment: Hi @seenukarthi do you know after I generate the token, how can I use it with JGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GitHub requires token-based authentication for all git operations using HTTP/HTTPS.

Generate a token and use it as below.

```java
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setURI( "https://github.com/xxx/testing.git" );
cloneCommand.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "<token>", "" ) );
cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\clone"));
cloneCommand.call();
```

Leave the password as blank and instead of username use the token.

Comment: Do you know why tokens better than pass and username? How is it more secure?

Comment: https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/#background check this fro benefits of token-based authentication